# C++ calling multiple constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to accomplish the following: I have 4 classes(lets call one primary, other 3 secondary ones) within one namespace, I want to store instances of secondary classes as private members of `primary`, to do this I need to call `secondary` constructors from `primary`'s one and then store instances. But Unfortunately I do not completely understand how to do it (not really experienced with c++): here is what I have in header file:

```
    class secondary_one
    {
    private:
        int number1;
    public:
        secondary_one(int);
        int get_number1() const;
    };

    class secondary_two
    {
    private:
        int number2;
    public:
        secondary_two(int);
        int get_number2() const;
    };

    class secondary_three
    {
    private:
        int number3;
    public:
        secondary_three(int);
        int get_number3() const;
    };
```

And 'primary' class is:

```
class primary
{
private:
    secondary_one one;
    secondary_two two;
    secondary_three three;
public:
    primary(int,int,int);
};
```

Upon calling `primary` constructor I want first argument to be send to constructor of `secondary_one`, second argument to constructor of `secondary_two` and so on.
And then store instances as private members. Is it even possible or I am just wasting time? If it is, can you give a short example what should I have in header and source file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the constructor initialization list:

```
class primary
{
public:
  primary(int a, int b, int c) : one(a), two(b), three(c) {}
private:
    secondary_one one;
    secondary_two two;
    secondary_three three;
};
```